# Concatenate character and string literal

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char, concatenation

My issue is the part:

`error_print(argv[0], "invalid option -- '" << (char)optopt << "'");`

I know I can't use `<<`, but I also can't use `+`. Because it gives error:

`error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'`

How can I pass it as a string to my `error_print` function?

It may seem like over kill but I use it ~20 times, I just made the demo really simple.

PS: I can use C++11.

```
void error_print(string name, string error) {
    cerr << name << ": " << error << endl << endl;
    cerr << "Usage: " << name << " [-a -b]" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool a_flag = false;
    bool b_flag = false;

    opterr = 0;

    int c;
    while (1) {
        struct option long_options[] =                  
        {
            {"alpha",  no_argument,       0, 'a'}, 
            {"beta",  no_argument,    0, 'b'},
            {0, 0, 0, 0}
        };
        e.
        int option_index = 0;

        c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "ab",long_options, &option_index);

        if (c == -1)
            break;

        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 'a':
                a_flag = true;
                break;
            case 'b':
                b_flag = true;
                break;
            case '?':
                error_print(argv[0], "invalid option -- '" << (char)optopt << "'");
                break;                                              
            default:
                error_print(argv[0], "");
                break;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I also can't use +" - but `operator+` is part of C++11, so why not?

Comment: @H2CO3 Updating error occuring with  `+`

Comment: @0x499602D2 This wont work

Comment: Just a small note: this code was close to an obscure runtime crash: `"whatever" + (char)optopt` implicitly converts `optopt` to an array index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use + for literal strings and a single character, but you can use it for std::string, so use

```
"invalid option -- '" + std::string(1, optopt) + "'"
```

Comment: It might be clearer to convert the first operand into a string: `std::string("invalid option -- '") + (char)optopt + "'"` - this doesn't rely on the type of `optopt` and seems a more general solution

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler is sufficiently new (draft C++14):

```
"invalid option -- '"s + char(optopt) + "'"s
```

This feature can be added to C++11 as it has the language support, (the `s` literal is not provided by the Standard library until C++14)

```
std::string operator "" s(const char* str, std::size_t len)
{
    return {str,len};
}
```